# Как отправить одно сообщение, а не несколько?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telegram

Проблема в следующем, написал парсер. Отправляю сообщение. Вместо одного сообщения с текстом, я получаю несколько. Как мне отправить одним?

```
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['гороскоп'])
    async def send_goroskop(message: types.Message):
    
        url = 'https://test/goroskop'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        quotes = soup.find_all('div', class_='goroskop-items-description')
    
        for quote in quotes:

             await message.reply(f'{quote.text}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильно не отправлять сообщения в цикле.

что-то вроде этого

```
    msg = ''
    for quote in quotes:
         msg += quote.text
    await message.reply(msg)
```